# Find the closure of the following set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Hello guys I was revising and I saw this question but didn't know what is the steps to show it

Also sorry for not being familiar with who to type math notations here

https://m.imgur.com/sUvIRci

Comment: There is a basic MathJax tutorial and quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a hint, the closure of a set is the set with all of it's limit points. So for instance, the closure of the rationals $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb R$ is formed by taking the limits of $\mathbb Q$. I don't want to give you the answer, I want to motivate it. I am sorry if this didn't help.